# JS Regular Expression Error: Unterminated character class

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one regular expression:

```
var regex = /[.．·・⋯•。~～〜><'"()%/\\]/g;
```

And I'm trying to define the pattern as string, then declare it as regular expression like this:

```
var charToFiltered = `[.．·・⋯•。~～〜><'"()%/\\]`;
var regexA = new RegExp(charToFiltered, 'g');
```

But I get the following Error:

> Invalid regular expression: /[.．·・⋯•。~～〜><'"()%/]/: Unterminated
>   character class

Comment: Change the ```\\``` to ```\\\\``` to prevent the closing `]` from being escaped so that it represents an escaped slash.

Comment: Hi @phuzi, thanks for your comment, it does work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you move backslash to the start of the character set:

```js
var charToFiltered = `[\\.．·・⋯•。~～〜><'"()%/]`;
var regexA = new RegExp(charToFiltered, 'g'); 
console.log(regexA);
```

The reason for that is your `\\` turns into single backslash and then you have `\]` construction in your regexp which means `]` literally. So your closing bracket becomes a part of the character class, and then you miss the actual closing `]`. All you need to do to resolve that is to move the backslash to someplace where it doesn't escape anything.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! It means if I change the order of my characters like this: **var charToFiltered = `[.．·・⋯•。~～〜\\><'"()%/]`**,  it should work in my case, and it does :)

Comment: Actually I wanna match the backslash, so it have to be **var charToFiltered = `[\\\\.．·・⋯•。~～〜><'"()%/]`;** , or it won't match when `regexA.test("\\")`

Comment: you don't have to escape it twice (via `\\\\`) if you put it at the start of the character set